# Designing API that can handle different resource identifiers

Tags: rest

I'm developing a set of URI's for a RESTful API. The API will be consumed by at least two clients.

Client 1 is actually the app itself, and it makes the most sense to identify resources using the primary key from the database. It would use a route such as:

/api/v1/products/:product_id

Client 2 does not know the internal primary keys of Client 1. Instead, it has it's own set of identifiers that Client 1 is aware of. It would use a route such as:

/api/v1/products/:product_identifier

Obviously, these two route would conflict. Two solutions I've thought of are:

1. Namespace the API used by client 2. Something like:
   /api/client2/v1/products/:product_identifier
2. Make client 2 do two calls. The first to get the internal id of the app, and the second to make the appropriate call.

Are there any other options that I may not have thought of? Neither of those options seem particularly appealing to me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: passing a `clientId` or equivalent as a parameter seems like the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use `/api/v1/products/abc` and `/api/v1/products/id:123`. Btw. the URI structure does not really matter, because the clients follow hyperlinks (HATEOAS).